# Javascript dom 2 basics

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm working on an assignment in which we need to use dom 2 in order to validate some user input, however I'm having a hard time just getting the basics. Between my professors accent and horrible writing its hard to make things out but this code I wrote up

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form checking</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style type="text/css">
        span{
            visibility: hidden;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function invalid(event){
            var val = event.target.value;
            var regex = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
            if(val.match(regex))
                document.getElementById("error").style.visibility = hidden;
            else
                document.getElementById("error").style.visibility = visible;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <span id="error">Should be in form xxx-xxx-xxxx</span><br>

    Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phoneNumber">

    <script>
        var pn = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");
        pn.addEventListener("blur", invalid, false);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

follows his notes exactly, or as close as I've been able to decipher, yet I can't even slightly get it to work let alone trying to do the assignment. Can someone please point out what is wrong with it? And please keep it simple I've only been taking the class for 2 weeks so I know next to nothing.

Comment: What is `hidden`, what is `visible`. Did you mean to use strings, and not variables?

Comment: their css keywords, part of visibility. hidden will cause the text to not be shown and visible will cause them to be shown. I'm not sure of their inner workings but I've used them before and I know this is the correct way to use them & to get my desired effect, well at least the way I was taught.

Comment: Yes, they are CSS keywords. However, you're declaring styles in the `<script>` tags now. Now that you're writing Javascript, words without quotes are either *Javascript* keywords or variables. The string allows it to be parsed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this: http://jsfiddle.net/6D2cJ/

You forgot to put quotes on the style visibility. It was expecting a variable but instead received nothing. Putting quotes around it makes a string.

Also, you forgot to add curly brackets for the `if` and `else` statement.

```
function invalid(event){
        var val = event.target.value;
        var regex = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
if(val.match(regex)) {
            document.getElementById("error").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
else {
            document.getElementById("error").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. On a side note I am much more familiar with c & c++ and in them you are allowed to omit {} in control statements if you have only one line of code, is that not true in javascript?

Comment: Yes, it works through out Java, C, C++ and Javascript as far as I know. However, I believe it only works if you have the if statement and block in the same line. Not too sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.. fixed some syntax errors and other stuff:

```
function invalid(event){
    var val = event.target.value;
    var regex = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
    if(!val.match(regex)){
       document.getElementById("error").style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
       document.getElementById("error").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
  var pn = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");
  pn.addEventListener("blur", invalid, false);
```

Working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/x84J2/24/

Comment: Oh.. there were no answers on this when I started :| where did they all come from :S